# Sharepoint Hyperlink / Picture column type

Tags: sharepoint

I am using the Hyperlink / Picture column type within a Document Library.

When entering the hyperlink, I am using a shortened path.  However, after exporting this site to an stp, I realized that it was being stored as the full path (it was failing when the stp was used in another Site Collection).

As an example, I entered the following path: /SC/Images1/AdministratorUsers.png
However, when viewing the entered docuemnt library item, I see this path:  http://servername:port/SC/Images1/AdministratorUsers.png

How do I get around this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, sharepoint saves only full urls. I circumvent this by storing all css and images etc in the root site(collection)'s style library. 
Even a publishing page's pagelayout url is stored as a full url, we had to create a tool to update all references when the site was moved to a new url / server...

Comment: What's interesting is that the Image Web part does not store the full url.. it stores them as I entered it above (/SC/Images1/AdministratorUsers.png )

Comment: Not an oficial bug tho, more like 'working as intended'. This is sharepoint's way to assure integrity in links. You see that behavior in lots of functionalities, more like a design decision. They did that believing they could relink everything when restoring, and that's where the FAIL begun :)